# I am trying to create a next button in vb.net to navigate through my access database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, navigation

The problem is that no matter from which position I start, everytime I press next it starts from the 1st record and then moves forward properly whereas I want it to start from the position I am at. 
I am really new to programming and have been struggling with this for 2 days :( 
Here is the code for that form

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Details
    Private Sub ShowData(CurrentRow)
        Try
            TbxSName.Text = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows(CurrentRow)("Scientific_Name")
            TbxCName.Text = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows(CurrentRow)("Common_Name")
            TbxDescription.Text = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows(CurrentRow)("Description")
            TbxEdibilty.Text = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows(CurrentRow)("Edibility")
            TbxLocation.Text = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows(CurrentRow)("Location")
            TbxMorphology.Text = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows(CurrentRow)("Morphology")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, "error")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub clr()
        TbxSName.Clear()
        TbxCName.Clear()
        TbxDescription.Clear()
        TbxEdibilty.Clear()
        TbxLocation.Clear()
        TbxMorphology.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Details_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call connection()

        Currentrow = 0

        Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Mushrooms", cn)

        Dad.Fill(Dst, "Mushrooms")
        ShowData(Currentrow)



    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click
        Call connection()

        If Currentrow = Dst.Tables("Mushrooms").Rows.Count - 1 Then
            MsgBox("Last Record is Reached", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            Currentrow += 1
                ShowData(Currentrow)
            End If

        cn.Close()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Don't include empty event procedures in your code.

Comment: What does `which position I start` mean? Is it the position when the program closed last time? If so, you can refer to [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings). Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call a connection from somewhere. Create it where it is used. Connections need to be closed and disposed. Using blocks accomplish this for you even if there is an error. You don't seem to need a DataAdapter or a DataSet in the code you presented. Just use a DataTable and a Command.

Since you haven't shared where or how you declared Currentrow, I can't tell you why it isn't updating. Also you haven't shared the ShowData method so I can't tell if something is going wrong there.

```
Private conString As String = "Your connection string"
Private CurrentRow As Integer
Private dt As DataTable

Private Sub Details_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dt = New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(conString),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Mushrooms", cn)
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    CurrentRow = 0
    ShowData()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click
    If CurrentRow >= dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Last Record is Reached")
    Else
        CurrentRow += 1
        ShowData()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowData()
    TbxSName.Text = dt.Rows(CurrentRow)("Scientific_Name").ToString
    TbxCName.Text = dt.Rows(CurrentRow)("Common_Name").ToString
    TbxDescription.Text = dt.Rows(CurrentRow)("Description").ToString
    TbxEdibilty.Text = dt.Rows(CurrentRow)("Edibility").ToString
    TbxLocation.Text = dt.Rows(CurrentRow)("Location").ToString
    TbxMorphology.Text = dt.Rows(CurrentRow)("Morphology").ToString
End Sub
```